# How to make Box redirect URI dynamic as redirect_uri can not be empty if you try to edit an app

Tags: oauth-2.0, box-api, box, boxapiv2

Box OAuth redirect uri can be empty only when creating a new App. If you try to edit the App, redirect_uri becomes mandatory. Can someone please tell me, how to make the redirect_uri dynamic?Meaning, redirect authentication code to a server whichever is making the request.

The steps,

1. Create an app in 'app.box.com/developers/services' (redirect_uri is blank).
2. Make a authorize request 'app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=https://www.xyz.com'.

   This properly redirects the code to 'https://www.xyz.com?code=XXXXXXX'
3. But, when i try to edit the App, say I want to add an image etc., then, redirect_uri is mandatory.

Now how to make redirect_uri dynamic? I am trying to make API call using box-sdk-java-v2.

Comment: Just saw box-sdk-ios supports something like 'boxsdk-YOUR_CLIENT_ID://boxsdkoauth2redirect', but the same doesn't work with box-java-sdk-v2.

Comment: If redirect_uri is blank, authorize request 'app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=https://www.xyz.com';, will properly redirects the authorization code to 'https://www.xyz.com?code=XXXXXXX';

This is possible only when redirect_uri is blank. 
redirect_uri is blank only when App is created, but if we try to edit the App, then, redirect_uri is mandatory